# How to pass arguments to a variadic macro?

Tags: c, function, macros, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I have a variadic function:

```
LogWrite(FILE * fp, int level, const char * filename, const char * function, ...)
```

It should be called like this:

```
LogWrite(fp, int Level, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, "Message: %s", message)
```

However, I want to write a variadic macro to make it easier to call:

```
1: #define LOGWRITE_L1(...) LogWrite(file, 1, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, ...)
or
2: #define LOGWRITE_L1(file, ...) LogWrite(file, 1, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, ...)
```

This is so that a developer can call it using:

```
LOGWRITE_L1(myfile, "Hello!");
```

instead of

```
LogWrite(myfile, 1, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, "Hello!")
```

However, both those methods give me a compiler error.

```
1: expected expression before '...'
2:'file' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Is this possible or am I wasting my time? I have never used variadic functions before, so not sure. My function works...I called it using the complete declaration and it wrote to the files that I wanted it to.

Comment: You seem to have misplaced `int Level` in your sample code... (I'm pretty sure I know what you mean, but better to let you fix it.)

Comment: Thanks for that!! Haha, that would have been awkward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put `__VA_ARGS__` as the replacement for the variadic arguments:

```
#define LOGWRITE_L1(file, ...) LogWrite(file, 1, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

This is only part of C99, C11 and C++11 standards. Some compilers offer extensions pertaining to the handling of variadic macros; check your manual.

Answer (score 4):

Use `__VA_ARGS__` instead of `...`

```
#define LOGWRITE_L1(file, ...) LogWrite(file, 1, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
```